# Can I not define (:::) in Haskell? Is it protected from use somehow?

Tags: haskell

I got this error, but as far as I can tell, it should work. What am I missing?

```
Not in scope: data constructor ':::'
        |
        | (:::) = cons
        | ^^^^^
```

There's also a similar error for the `infixr 5 :::` declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably missing that

> An operator symbol starting with a colon is a constructor.

-- [The Haskell 2010 language report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4)

Use in a constructor declaration should work:

```
data Foo a b = a ::: b
```

Comment: It's also in Haskell 98

Comment: @FilipHaglund even in Haskell 1.0 actually, but why not link to the current report?

Comment: Assumed it might have been added, so I pointed it out for anyone using Haskell 98. Maybe that's not how things work in Haskell land?

Comment: @FilipHaglund Your remark is fine. As for "maybe that's not how things work in Haskell land", it is true that almost everyone uses GHC >= 7.x (which defaults to Haskell 2010), and that the standard language has been evolving at a measured pace  -- cf. how the features introduced in the 2010 report had mostly been bread-and-butter in GHC for a long time, or, for that matter, the number of widespread GHC extensions no one bats an eyelid about. (FWIW, when I link to the 2010 Report I don't point out the version explicitly unless the specific version matters for the poin't I'm making.)

Comment: @FilipHaglund Makes sense. As for how things work in Haskell land - I'm no expert really, so listen to duplode.